# Building VS 2003 Solution Using Devenv.com on Build Server With Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tfsbuild, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

I am trying to build .NET Framework 1.1 solution (VS 2003) on a TFS build server 2008 which is on windows server 2008 R2 machine. I am following the instructions from this website

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nagarajp/archive/2005/10/26/485368.aspx

and going for the second solution suggested. The build server goes through the first 4 steps fine (Initializing build, Getting Sources, Labelling Sources and Compiling Sources for any cpu/release) but after then it just shows that Build in progress and does not do anything.  I left the job running overnight and it still shows Buiid In progress. I checked the event log and it displays the following message:

```
The application (Visual Studio .NET 2003, from vendor Microsoft) has the following problem: Visual Studio .NET 2003 has a known compatibility issue with this version of Windows.
```

When i log in to the build server and then try opening Visual Studio 2003, it shows me a pop up window with the same message and then i have to click Run Program to go further. But since i am building the solution using command line, i am wondering how can i do that? I have also tried to run this program in compatibility mode (windows xp service pack 3) and checked the options "Disabe visual themes" and "Disable desktop composition" but no luck. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the modified version of the configuration file for 1.1 Framework project to get build with Build Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="DesktopBuild"     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
```

```
<ProjectExtensions>
<ProjectFileVersion>2</ProjectFileVersion>
<Description></Description>
<BuildMachine>UNKNOWN</BuildMachine>
</ProjectExtensions>
<PropertyGroup>
<TeamProject>1.1 Framework</TeamProject>
<BuildDirectoryPath>UNKNOWN</BuildDirectoryPath>
<DropLocation>\\UNKNOWN\drops</DropLocation>
<RunTest>false</RunTest>
<RunCodeAnalysis>Never</RunCodeAnalysis>
<WorkItemType>Bug</WorkItemType>
<WorkItemFieldValues>System.Reason=Build Failure;System.Description=Start the build    using Team Build</WorkItemFieldValues>
<WorkItemTitle>Build failure in build:</WorkItemTitle>
<DescriptionText>This work item was created by Team Build on a build failure. </DescriptionText>
<BuildlogText>The build log file is at:</BuildlogText>
<ErrorWarningLogText>The errors/warnings log file is at:</ErrorWarningLogText>
<UpdateAssociatedWorkItems>true</UpdateAssociatedWorkItems>
<AdditionalVCOverrides></AdditionalVCOverrides>
<CustomPropertiesForClean></CustomPropertiesForClean>
<CustomPropertiesForBuild></CustomPropertiesForBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release|Any CPU">
<FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
<PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
</ConfigurationToBuild>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
<VS2003_Devenv>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET    2003\Common7\IDE\devenv.com</VS2003_Devenv> 
<VS2003_Configuration>Release</VS2003_Configuration> 
</PropertyGroup> 
<ItemGroup>
<VS2003_OutputFiles Include="$(SolutionRoot)\DSC.STARS\Main\DSC.STARS.Web\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="AfterCompile">  
<Exec Command="&quot;$(VS2003_Devenv)&quot; &quot;$(SolutionRoot)\DSC.STARS\Main\DSC.STARS.SOLUTION.sln&quot; /build release" />  
 <MakeDir Directories="$(BinariesRoot)\$(VS2003_Configuration)"  Condition="!Exists('$(BinariesRoot)\$(VS2003_Configuration)')" />

<Copy SourceFiles="@(VS2003_OutputFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(VS2003_OutputFiles- >'$(BinariesRoot)\$(VS2003_Configuration)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
</Target>
</Project>
```